# At least one of your delays must be synchronized to clock. ?? (pro tools Plugin)

Tags: pro-tools

What does it mean?
Can any one explain me ?

Comment: what's the context of this question?

Answer (score 1):

I expect it's the master clock of the session. But you really need to be more specific with your questions - this is the second ultra-vague one line question asked here. It's really a waste of everyone's time, including yours.